# Launch forms in dialog - SharePoint Online/Modern Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, modal-dialog, modern-experience

I have been trying to manoeuvre my way around the new Modern lists in SharePoint.

I have set Launch Forms In Dialog to YES however the form for the list does not open in a modal or dialog. It does work for lists that are still using the old experience.

Anything that can be done to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Did you ever figure out any solutions for this? I've just begun trying out the new modern sites and was wondering this exact same thing. :-)

Comment: Hey buddy. Unfortunately no, unless you try something programmatically using the SharePoint framework perhaps you might be able to achieve something. Out of the box though this doesn’t seem possible